# How to get the values of selected columns in an update

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, sql-update

I want to make a single query to update and select columns, like

```
UPDATE dbo.employees SET otp = $OTP
WHERE identification = $identity (SELECT mail,emp.id, emp.name FROM dbo.emails email
LEFT JOIN dbo.employees emp ON emp.id = email.employee 
WHERE emp.identification = $identity)
```

How do I get the selected column values

Comment: WHY do you want to make a single query to update and select?

Comment: Try the `OUTPUT` clause...

Comment: i want to update the otp  on the database and send an email on the selected mail and name

Comment: @DaleK when i separate queries i am able to achieve that. but my supervisor asked me to combine the two statement.  running this in sql it returns the values but i cant find away to do this execute this in php

Comment: DaleK suggested to use [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql), which is something that the posted code does not do. Have you considered it?

Comment: Is there a one-to-one relationship between `emails` and `employees`? Also your code is **dangerously** open to SQL injection

Comment: @Charlieface yes its a one -to- one relation. this is what what am trying to achieve  $OTP = generateOTP();
$sql =  ("UPDATE db01.dbo.employees SET otp = $OTP WHERE identification =$identity (SELECT mail,emp.id, emp.name FROM db01.dbo.emails email LEFT JOIN db01.dbo.employees emp ON emp.id = email.employee WHERE emp.identification = $identity)");
$emailOtp = $con->query($sql);
$emailTo = NULL;
$name = NULL;
if($emailOtp){
foreach ($emailOtp as $value) {
$emailTo = $value['mail'];
$name = $value['name'];
 }
  }

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to achieve this.

You have a couple more issues with your code:

- You *must* parameterize your statements, or you leave yourself open to dangerous SQL injection.
- You don't need to loop the result if you only expect one row.
- A `LEFT JOIN` followed by `WHERE` on one of the joined table's columns makes it an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

```php
$OTP = generateOTP();
$sql = "
UPDATE emp
SET otp = @OTP
OUTPUT email.mail, inserted.name
FROM dbo.employees emp
INNER JOIN dbo.emails email ON emp.id = email.employee
WHERE emp.identification = @identity;
";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('@identity', $identity);
$stmt->bindParam('@OTP', $OTP);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $row = stsmt->fetch();
    $emailTo = $row['mail'];
    $name = $row['name'];
} else {
    // deal with errors
}
```

This code only works where `emails` is in a one-to-one relationship with `employees`. Otherwise you must use a separate `SELECT`.

Comment: thanks its working, i removed the '@' and used a ?.

Answer (score 0):

you can use store procedure

```
create procedure spupdate_employees_mail
@OTP int,
@IDENT varchar(20)
AS BEGIN

UPDATE employees SET OTP=@OTP WHERE identification=@IDENT

SELECT mail,employees.id,employees.name from  emails
LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=emails.id
WHERE employees.identification=@IDENT
END

EXECUTE spupdate_employees_mail 1001,'mechanic'
```

spupdate_employees_mail take two parameter (otp as int and identification as varchar).It will update the table- employess and then fetch data from employees and emalis table on LEFT JOIN